# Python for re.match re.sub

Tags: python, html, csv, text, match

Working on a csv file. It contains a list of sources (simple ssl links), places, websites (< a >not ssl links< / a >), Direcciones, and emails. When some data is not avaliable, it simply doesn't appears. Like this:

```
httpsgoogledotcom, GooglePlace2, Direcciones, Montain View, Email, googplace@yourplace.com
```

Nevertheless website 'a html tag' links always appear twice and followed by several commas. Likewise, the commas are followed, sometimes by Direcciones, and sometimes by sources (https). Thus, if the process doesn't break when EOF, it can be 'replacing' for hours and creating an output file with gbs of redudant and missplaced information. Let's pick up four entries as an example of Reutput.csv:

```
> httpsgoogledotcom, GooglePlace, Website, "<a> href='httpgoogledotcom'></a>",,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
> "<a href='httpgoogledotcom'></a>",,,,,,,,,,,,, 
> ,,Direcciones, Montain View, Email, googplace@yourplace.com
> httpsbingdotcom, BingPlace, Direcciones, MicroWorld, Email, bing@yourplace.com
> httpsgoogledotcom, GooglePlace, Website, "<a> href='httpgoogledotcom'></a>",,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
> "<a href='httpgoogledotcom'></a>",,,,,,,,,,,,, 
> httpsbingdotcom, BingPlace, Direcciones, MicroWorld, Email, bing@yourplace.com
```

So the idea is deleting the unnecessary website 'a html tag' link and the excess of commas, but respecting the new lines /n and not falling on the loop. Like this:

```
> httpsgoogledotcom, GooglePlace, Website, "<a href='httpgoogledotcom'></a>",Direcciones, Montain View, Email, googplace@yourplace.com 
> httpsbingdotcom, BingPlace, Direcciones,MicroWorld, Email, bing@yourplace.com
> httpsgoogledotcom, GooglePlace,Website, <a href='httpgoogledotcom'></a>"
> httpsbingdotcom, BingPlace, Direcciones, MicroWorld, Email, bing@yourplace.com
```

This is the last version of the code:

```
with open('Reutput.csv') as reuf, open('Put.csv', 'w') as putuf:
    text = str(reuf.read())
    for lines in text:
        d = re.match('</a>".*D?',text,re.DOTALL)
        if d is not None:
            if not 'https' in d:
                replace = re.sub(d,'</a>",Direc',lines)
        h = re.match('</a>".*?http',text,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
        if h is not None:
            if not 'Direc' in h:
                replace = re.sub(h,'</a>"\nhttp',lines)
        replace = str(replace)
        putuf.write(replace)
```

Now I get a Put.csv file with the last row repeated forever. Why this loop? I have already tried several approaches to this code but, sadly, I am still stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got with the code by myself. I am posting it here hoping someone finds it useful. Thank you anyway for your help and the negative votes!

```
import re
with open('Reutput.csv') as reuf, open('Put.csv', 'w') as putuf:
    text = str(reuf.read())
    d = re.findall('</a>".*?Direc',text,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
    if d is not None:
        for elements in d:
            elements = str(elements)
            if not 'https' in elements:
                    s = re.compile('</a>".*?Direc',re.DOTALL)
                    replace = re.sub(s,'</a>",Direc',text)
    h = re.findall('</a>".*?https',text,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
    if h is not None:
        for elements in h:
            if not 'Direc' in elements:
                s = re.compile('</a>".*?https',re.DOTALL)
                replace = re.sub(s,'</a>"\nhttps',text)
        replace = str(replace)
        putuf.write(replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is no match, `groups` will be `None`. You'll need to guard against this (or refactor the regex so that it always matches something).

```
    groups = re.search('</a>".*?Direc',lines,re.DOTALL)
    if groups is not None:
        if not 'https' in groups:
```

Notice the addition of the `not None` condition and the subsequent indentation of the following lines which it governs.

Comment: I tried it and I got a blank file, so you are right, groups' match must be None. Why? And how to fix Reutput.csv then? Thanks in advance tripleee